# Magento 2 : price issue

Tags: magento2, product, price, multistore, store-view

I am using Magento ver. 2.4.2 EE & React Frontend

In front-end when switching the region between US/UK/EU the price sign is still in $ (us dollar)

[image]

Can you please share which things i can check to make sure its not related to any admin setting/changes ?

currency is also setup properly

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you using Multi Store?

Comment: yes, i have multistore website

Comment: Any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 0):

1. **Setup currency: Move to menu Stores >> Configuration. Under GENERAL tab you will find sub menu Currency Setup. Setup Currency
   Options with what you need and click Save Config.**
2. **Setup currency rates: Move menu to Stores >> Currency Rates. Set value for all parameters and hit Saves Currency Rates**

Comment: currency is also setup properly

Comment: on all store views?

Comment: Yes see - https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/9670267?key=97adc994ecd953d444fd5b7012e72abd

Comment: In UK Store in frontend i am seeing US dollar values, i have checked the currency & its allowed